# LibGDX DragAndDrop - Drag stop is called immidiatly after drag

Tags: android-studio, drag-and-drop, libgdx

Im currently developing a basic game for Android, but I'm having a big problem with the com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils library.

When I started the project I used Eclipse and the DragAndDrop-functionality worked great, but after a while I experienced problems with Gradle which led me to change to Android Studio. So after exporting my project to Android studio, the DragAndDrop just stopped working. When I click a dragobject and start to drag it, it stops immediately and DragStop() is called.

Now I feel I have tried everything there is and the only lead is this thread: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2901 which is basicly the same behavior, but it's caused by something else. By "lead" I mean that maybe the change of LibGDX version is the problem? I have not investigated this any further.

Anyway, I can't even get this simple DragAndDrop example to work:

```
dragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
    dragAndDrop.addSource(new DragAndDrop.Source(splashActor)
    {
        @Override
        public DragAndDrop.Payload dragStart(InputEvent event, float x,
                                 float y,int pointer)
        {
            DragAndDrop.Payload payload = new DragAndDrop.Payload();
            payload.setObject(splashActor);
            payload.setDragActor(splashActor);
            return payload;
        }

    });

    dragAndDrop.addTarget(new DragAndDrop.Target(pauseButton)
    {
        @Override
        public boolean drag(DragAndDrop.Source source, DragAndDrop.Payload payload,
                            float x, float y, int pointer)
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void drop(DragAndDrop.Source source, DragAndDrop.Payload payload,
                         float x, float y, int pointer)
        {
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help or ideas regarding this problem. I would be truly grateful if I could get my game working again!

Comment: Which version are you using? That issue was fixed 8 days ago. The latest stable libgdx version is 26 days old (1.5.4). Are you using 1.5.5-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Really? It would be awesome if that is true! I'm currently using version 1.5.2. Android Studio is not able to find the 1.5.5-snapshot. Do I have to wait, or is it possible to fix manually?

Comment: 1.5.5-SNAPSHOT is already available. https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx/1.5.5-SNAPSHOT/ Maybe you need to add `maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }` to your repositories.

Comment: I forgot the -SNAPSHOT part. When I added the newest version it worked! Thank you so much! I'm new to adding posts on stackoverflow, so I don't really know what to do from here. Can I give you credit somehow?

Comment: Don't worry. I'm here to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed by updating the libgdx version to 1.5.5-SNAPSHOT! Thanks to noone for solving this.